# Google maps API v3 not showing position correctly

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to apply a Google Maps API v.3 that shows position of a user by latitude and longitude in Ruby on Rails app. But when i visit a page in which map should appear i've got blank div until i refresh page with it. Then maps appears correctly. Here's the script i use for.

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var map, mapOptions, marker, myLatlng;
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng($("p#latitude").html(), $("p#longitude").html());
    mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    return marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Ahoy!"
    });
  });
```

Also i include `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" style=""></script>` and `<script src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/14/11/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

What can be the problem?

I removed gem turbolinks from Gemfile and deleted 'require turbolinks' from application.js and now it works properly.

Comment: Is that your whole code?

Comment: For js? Sure. Of course all this includes into html document, where is  two containers "#latitude" and "#longitude". But even when i'm pass coordinates not with variables but with exact numbers - it works only after page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have answered your own question, but just in case others look this up: document.ready doesn't occur between pages when you're using turbolinks--essentially, turbolinks treats your whole app as one page.

There are two solutions to your problem: one, to get rid of turbolinks, which you did; or two, to attach your js to a specific turbolink event, such as page:load.